# Uniform Smoothness Inequality for Schatten Norms

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I'm looking for a proof of the inequality

$$
\left[ \frac12(\left\|A+B\right\|_p^p + \left\|A-B\right\|_p^p)\right]^{2/p} \leq \left\|A\right\|_p^2 +C_p \left\|B\right\|_p^2
$$

where A and B are complex matrices of the same size, $\left\| .\right\|_p$ refers to the Schatten p-norm,  p$\geq 2$, and $C_p=p-1$.

I have a reference for the opposite inequality when $1\leq p \leq 2$ but no mention of the one above. Are the two somehow equivalent? Am I missing an easy argument to follow one out of the other?

Comment: Is this a duplicate?

Comment: It was supposed to be an edit, I've deleted the other post.